# Best way for a user within a BSD jail to have full access to a particular user's files on the hosting system

Tags: bsd, file-access, jail

This happens to be a TrueNAS (BSD) system.  The system itself has an id of `pedz` with UID of 1000.  (I'll call him Gpedz).  I created a jail so I could write an application and run it safely on the NAS and created a user of `pedz` within the jail which was given a UID of 1002.  I'll call him Jpedz.

The application will be running as Jpedz but will need access to the files owned Gpedz including the ability to remove files.

I could edit the /etc/passwd file in the jail and make the Jpedz UID 1000 and I bet that would solve my problem but I'm wondering if there is a more accepted way to solve this issue.

Comment: Did the comments or my answer solve your issue? If the answer helped, you can say thanks by up voting and/or checking as answered.

Comment: Honestly, I never tried it.  I just set the uid and gid in the Jail to match the global system.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

### This should work as expected:

- Make sure their home directory is a zfs filesystem:

  `/usr/home/pedz`
- Add something like this to the jail rc.conf file:

  `jail_pedz_mount_enable="YES"`
- Add this to the jail /etc/fstab:

  `/usr/home/pedz   /jails/j1/usr/ports  nullfs  rw,noatime  0  0`